# Multiple argument for a WCF web service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, wcf, entity-framework

I want to create a WCF webservice to create a user . So i implemented the service and the interface :

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method="POST" ,UriTemplate = "AddUser/{id}/{login}/{pwd}/{prenom}/{nom}/{email}")]
    void AddUser(string id ,string login ,string pwd ,string prenom ,string nom ,string email);
```

and the implementation of the service is :

```
 public void AddUser(string id, string login, string pwd, string prenom, string nom, string email)
   {
       int userId = Convert.ToInt32(id);

       using (Entities entities = new Entities())
       {
           usr user = new usr();
           user.CIN = userId;
           user.login = login;
           user.pwd = pwd;
           user.prenom = prenom;
           user.nom = nom;
           user.email = email;


           entities.users.Add(user);
           entities.SaveChanges();

       }
   }
```

this is the web config

```
 <services>
  <service name="PfeWebservices.ProjectWebservices" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="PfeWebservices.IProjectWebservices"
               behaviorConfiguration="web">
    </endpoint>   
  </service>    
</services>
```

but when i run it with this Url :

```
http://localhost:53359/ProjectWebservices.svc/AddUser/13206874/malek/malek/malek/malek/malek
```

i get "Method not allowed"

what may be the problem knowing that the same service contain a get operation and it is working fine?

Comment: Do you have anything here first:  http://localhost:53359/ProjectWebservices.svc

Comment: Also, you are not providing DateNaiss even though it is part of the UriTemplate.  Try this: http://localhost:53359/ProjectWebservices.svc/AddUser/13206874/malek/malek/malek/malek/malek/2000-01-01

Comment: yes the service is working . i have another operation (GetAllUsers) and it is working fine @SQLDBA

Comment: i removed the DateNaiss and i know get Method not allowed @SQLDBA

Comment: Did you update the service reference in the client?

Answer (score 1):

When you run your browser with the URL provided, you actually fires of a Get-request on the method, and not a post-request. When your method only allows POST, the rest explains itself;) Try to run it using post:)

Comment: it is already done ( i edited the post with my web config ) @thsorens